# При включении плагина Autoptimize перестает работать сайт, ошибка белый экран, из за чего может возникать данная ошибка?

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте установлен плагин, Autoptimize.
Сайт имеет две языковых версии, мультиязычность реализована через плагин polylang.

При включении плагина Autoptimize а точнее опции в плагине lazy load для изображений перестает работать сайт (появляется белый экран), причем на основной версии сайта все работает нормально, ошибка появляется только на руссокой версии сайта.

Как понять из за чего может возникать ошибка?
Может кто то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, буду благодарен за совет)

Comment: Что в консоле пишет?

Comment: @Krya в консоле пусто((

Comment: включите wp_debug и проверьте, что за ошибка на сайте

Comment: @Krya Включал тоже пусто((